# Intuitive explanation for range of representable values

Tags: floating-point, precision

I'm a newbie and have recently started to read an introduction to floating-point number representations, which stated that the range of representable values in an arbitrary base b, for a minimum exponent value L and maximum exponent value U, can be found as follows:

- minimal value: b^(L-1)
- maximum value: b^U * (1-b^-t), where t is the number of significant digits in the mantissa

How should these be understood and/or derived, explained for a newbie?

Comment: Rutgersandmore  What part of `b^U * (1-b^-t)` is clear?  What part is unclear?

Comment: I thought that this expression might follow from the maximum of the expression for a given value x, which is (besides the sign in front) the summation over the expression a_j * b^e-j for indices j = 1..t (where a_j are the significant digits of the mantissa) -- but I just can't see how. I feel I may just miss a very simple arithmetic point here, I don't know... Or how could this max. value be derived otherwise?

Comment: Let `t = 5` for discussion, `b==10`. `1-b^-t` -->  1.0 -  0.00001 --> 0.99999.  The maximum exponent  (let U=7) is often reserved to represent infinity and Not-a-number. The max expo for finite numbers is then `U-1`.  So the max value is 0.99999 * pow(10,6) or 9.9999 * pow(10,7).

Comment: Makes a  lot more sense now -- I did not think about it like this beforehand, always tried to directly derive it from the sum expression. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Floating-point formats differ in some of their details and in how they are presented. Since the question does not specify these details, we have to infer some of the missing information.

Most commonly, the significand is normalized to the interval [1, *b*). However, given the information in the question, it looks like the normal interval is designated to be [1/*b*, 1).

In this case, a normal floating-point number consists of a sign (− or +), an exponent *e* in *L* ≤ *e* ≤ *U*, and a significand *f* in [1/*b*, 1) that is formed of *p* base-*b* digits after a radix point (such as .173<sub>8</sub> for three base-8 digits after the “.”). The number represented by these parts is ± *b*<sup>e</sup> • *f*. (The *t* in the question has been changed to *p* here, short for *precision*.)

With these parameters, the smallest representable positive number has sign +, exponent *L*, and significand 1/b (formed from .1000…000<sub>*b*</sub>). The number this represents is + *b*<sup>*L*</sup> • 1/*b* = *b*<sup>*L*−1</sup>.

The greatest representable finite number has sign +, exponent *U*, and the largest significand, which is .*nnn*…*nnn*<sub>b</sub>, where *n* is the digit *b*−1 and there are *p* digits. The value of .*nnn*…*nnn*<sub>b</sub> equals the value of the geometric series .*n* + .0*n* + .00*n* + .000*n* + .000…*n*, which is 1−*b*<sup>−*p*</sup>. Equivalently, we can see that .*nnn*…*nnn*<sub>b</sub> + *b*<sup>−*p*</sup> = .*nnn*…*nnn*<sub>b</sub> + .000…001<sub>b</sub> = 1.000…000<sub>b</sub> = 1. This sign, exponent, and significand represent + *b*<sup>*U*</sup> • (1−*b*<sup>−*p*</sup>).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, especially for pointing out the geometric series .n + .0n + .00n + .000n + .000 = 1−b^−p. I didn't make that link! Thank you so much!